# Action Policy - define exception message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I'm trying to integrate [actionpolicy](https://actionpolicy.evilmartians.io/#/) into a Rails 7.1 application, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to define custom exception messages.

My code is very basic

```
class InvestigationReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @investigation = Investigation.find(params[:investigation_id])
    authorize! @investigation, with: InvestigationReviewPolicy
  end
  ...
end
```

```
class InvestigationReviewPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def new?
    record.state == "completed"
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionPolicy::Unauthorized do |ex|
    p "details: #{ex.result.reasons.details}"
    p "full messages: #{ex.result.reasons.full_messages}" 
  end
  ...
end
```

And this is what my log looks like

```
web |   ↳ app/controllers/investigation_reviews_controller.rb:11:in `new'
web | "details: {}"
web | "full messages: []"
```

I'd like to display to the user a message saying the investigation is in the wrong state.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your cases, you don't have any reasons, it's just a rule failure. Reasons are only populate if you have `check?`, `allowed_to?` or `deny!` calls in your method. For example:

```
def new? = check?(:completed?)

def completed? = record.state == "completed"
```

Or with `deny!`:

```
def new?
  deny!(:incomplete) unless record.state == "completed"
  true
end
```

See https://actionpolicy.evilmartians.io/#/reasons

If you only want to know the rule that prevented access, you can access the corresponding information as follows:

```
rescue_from ActionPolicy::Unauthorized do |ex|
  ex.policy #=> InvestigationReviewPolicy
  ex.rule #=> :new?
  ex.result.message => Human-readable message generated via i18n
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://actionpolicy.evilmartians.io/#/i18n?id=translations-lookup):

> For example, given a `GuestUserPolicy` class which is inherited from `DefaultUserPolicy` and a rule `feed?`, the following list of possible translation keys would be used:
>
> ```
> [:"action_policy.policy.guest_user.feed?", :"action_policy.policy.default_user.feed?", :"action_policy.policy.feed?", :"action_policy.unauthorized"]
> ```

So in your case it's:

```yaml
en:
  action_policy:
    policy:
      investigation_review:
        new?: The investigation is in the wrong state
```

You need to use such structure in your locale YAML files